# Python Django Create Users With roles on what they can see?

Tags: python, django, web, database-security

Hello I have to make normal users with email verification and special_users that can accept a user that did apply demand form like this:

User Form after registration (Super_User cant see this form)

Name

Surname

Birthday

.

.

.

Upload an image
Passeport Number(Very important, to check if this user did ever apply to this platform while its unique)

The special user in the other hand will see a list of applicants(users)(Note that will be many special_users) like this and normal users cant see this list, because theirs acces is restricted here

Name Surname Country Student University

Name Surname Country Internship United Nations

Name Surname Country Internship Microsoft

Name Surname Country Employee Github

.

.

.

Name Surname Country Employee Github

Now if a special_user could click on a name, sort or search by the fields, in the end he can view a user application form that a new user did apply for, and special user could have the posibility to accept, if he accepts then the user is no longer on the list of applications he is only visible on the list of that super_user.

Other restrictions: If a user did make a registration with his email, but now he wants to make a double account to apply again he cant apply as that time as a super_user didnt accept his application form

A user can be blacklisted with a reason: 1) not a good person 2) bad neighbour

What I try to do is an index.html with login and the same index if logout.html if login granted users will have their content depending on what their roles are.
If Anyone can help, I use PYCHARM from Jetbrains, i am very new to Django but i have a big experience in python

[Image View of a normal User after being verified](http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn34/dardanshatri/ernesto_zpshu8yge0y.jpg)

[Super_User commun view of all super_users](http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn34/dardanshatri/tamara_zpseeud7rl6.jpg)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Django Permissions Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization)? It should set you down the right path.

Comment: I'v putted some images in the end to ilustrate better my @GJStein